# How do i run a Python script on a dynamic webpage with Flask and Socketio?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to use Flask and SocketIO, i found this example where some random numbers are printed dynamically in real time on a webpage.

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, copy_current_request_context
from random import random
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event


__author__ = 'slynn'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

#turn the flask app into a socketio app
socketio = SocketIO(app)

#random number Generator Thread
thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()

class RandomThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 1
        super(RandomThread, self).__init__()

    def randomNumberGenerator(self):
        """
        Generate a random number every 1 second and emit to a socketio instance (broadcast)
        Ideally to be run in a separate thread?
        """
        #infinite loop of magical random numbers
        print("Making random numbers")
        while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
            number = round(random()*10, 3)
            print(number)
            socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': number}, namespace='/test')
            sleep(self.delay)

    def run(self):
        self.randomNumberGenerator()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    #only by sending this page first will the client be connected to the socketio instance
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    # need visibility of the global thread object
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    #Start the random number generator thread only if the thread has not been started before.
    if not thread.isAlive():
        print("Starting Thread")
        thread = RandomThread()
        thread.start()

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app)
```

I have a Python script which connects to a Websocket, receives data and prints this data.

```
import websocket
from bitmex_websocket import Instrument
from bitmex_websocket.constants import InstrumentChannels
from bitmex_websocket.constants import Channels
import json

websocket.enableTrace(True)

channels = [
    InstrumentChannels.trade,
]

XBTUSD = Instrument(symbol='XBTUSD',
                    channels=channels)
XBTUSD.on('action', lambda msg: test(msg))


def test(msg):
    parsed = json.loads(json.dumps(msg))
    print(parsed)

XBTUSD.run_forever()
```

I now want to print this data on my webpage, i tried to "merge" these two scripts but apparently i can't, because to run the Websocket connector i have to run XBTUSD.run_forever(), which will start the process but it won't run the rest of the code, including the Flask part which generates the webpage, so only one at time can run.

Is there a way to make the Websocket connector communicate with the Flask/Socketio part so that the data from the Websocket connector is printed on the webpage?

Comment: _i have to run XBTUSD.run_forever()_ you can run it as a separate thread.

Comment: @Fian So i would have two different process. The thing is that i need to print with Flask a variable from the Websocket Connector, so i'd have to "share" a variable between the two threads. Is it possible?

Comment: _two different process_ no, thread ≠ process. _"share" a variable between the two threads_ yes, all threads in a same process share memory between them (i.e. all variables).

Comment: this makes sense. Thanks @Fian!